# Como desplegar alerta al presionar un boton, si ningun checkbox esta seleccionado, por medio de JavaScript. (solo si todos estan desmarcados)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Estoy buscando integrar una alerta que se active, de tal forma que si ninguno de los checkboxs esta marcado y presione un boton me proyecte un mensaje de alerta .
Pero para esto debe tomar en cuenta que ninguna de las 4 opciones este seleccionada, ya que de estar una sola, ya me esta realizando otro evento al presionar el boton de enviar.

trate de crear una condicion if con operadores && para que los tomara en cuenta solo si todas las opciones estaban deseleccionadas, mandaria ejecutar la alerta. (lo cual no resulto funcionar).

```
      <div>
<input type="checkbox" id="ExcelenteChk1" onclick="Disable1()">  1 
<input type="checkbox" id="BuenoChk1"onclick="Disable2()">  2
<input type="checkbox" id="RegularChk1"onclick="Disable3()">  3
<input type="checkbox" id="MaloCh1"onclick="Disable4()">  4


<div>
    <Button ID="BotonEncEnv"  Text="Enviar respuestas"    
        OnClick="BotonEncEnv_Click" OnClientClick="uncheck()" />
</div>



</div>


   <script type="text/javascript">


        function uncheck()
        {

            document.getElementById('ExcelenteChk1');
            document.getElementById('BuenoChk1');
            document.getElementById('RegularChk1');
            document.getElementById('MaloCh1');
           
  if ((ExcelenteChk1.uncheck = true) && (BuenoChk1.uncheck = true) && (RegularChk1.uncheck = true) && (MaloCh1.uncheck = true))
                     {
                alert("¡No has contestado la Seccion 1!");
            }

}

        function Disable1() {

            document.getElementById('ExcelenteChk1');
            document.getElementById('BuenoChk1');
            document.getElementById('RegularChk1');
            document.getElementById('MaloCh1');



            if (ExcelenteChk1.checked = true)

            {
                BuenoChk1.checked = false;
                RegularChk1.checked = false;
                MaloCh1.checked = false;
            } 


        }


        function Disable2() {

            document.getElementById('ExcelenteChk1');
            document.getElementById('BuenoChk1');
            document.getElementById('RegularChk1');
            document.getElementById('MaloCh1');


            if (BuenoChk1.checked = true)
            {
                ExcelenteChk1.checked = false;
                RegularChk1.checked = false;
                MaloCh1.checked = false;

            } 

        }


         function Disable3() {

            document.getElementById('ExcelenteChk1');
            document.getElementById('BuenoChk1');
            document.getElementById('RegularChk1');
            document.getElementById('MaloCh1');


                if (RegularChk1.checked = true) 
                {
                    ExcelenteChk1.checked = false;
                    BuenoChk1.checked = false;
                    MaloCh1.checked = false;

                }

         }



        function Disable4() {

            document.getElementById('ExcelenteChk1');
            document.getElementById('BuenoChk1');
            document.getElementById('RegularChk1');
            document.getElementById('MaloCh1');

            if (MaloCh1.checked = true) {
                ExcelenteChk1.checked = false;
                BuenoChk1.checked = false;
                RegularChk1.checked = false;

            }

        }


         
         
            
    </script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. ¿Estás tratando de trabajar solo con HTML + JS o también estás mezclando un poco de ASP? (lo digo por la sintaxis del botón). Si tu caso es lo primero, también podrías agregar tu código como _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`). Además, no estás comparando en los `if`, ¡estás asignando! No es lo mismo `if (a = b)` que `if (a == b)`. Revisá la [sintaxis del `if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Answer (score 2):

Hay un par de cosas mal:

Un solo signo de igual (=) es operador de asignacion, no de comparación. Para comparar (verificar una condición) debes usar 2 (== con coercion del tipo) o 3 (=== sin coercion de tipo).

La condición que buscas verificar no es `.uncheck == true`, más bien es `checked == false` o `!checked`.

Entonces, en vez de esto:

```
if ((ExcelenteChk1.uncheck = true) && (BuenoChk1.uncheck = true) && (RegularChk1.uncheck = true) && (MaloCh1.uncheck = true))
```

intenta esto:

```js
const excelente = document.getElementById('excelente')
const bueno = document.getElementById('bueno')
const malo = document.getElementById('malo')
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!excelente.checked && !bueno.checked && !malo.checked) {
    alert('Debes elegir una opcion')
    } else {
      console.log('hay opciones seleccionadas')
    }
  })
```

```html
<input id='excelente' type='checkbox'>
<input id='bueno' type='checkbox'>
<input id='malo' type='checkbox'>

<button id='btn'>Submit</button>
```